# Unblock controls if !Page.IsValid

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have ASP.NET WebForms application. One of it's pages is dynamically created table with `RegularExpressionValidator`. Above of table there are several `LinkButtons`, which manages navigation of application. But if I put invalid value to textbox in table, `Page.IsValid` is set to false and all controls on page are blocked.

So, how can I unblock buttons even if validator set `Page.IsValid` to false? Thnak you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to "unblock" the link buttons used for navigation, you can use:

`CausesValidation="False"`

in the ASPX markup for the link button.

Example:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnBack" runat="server" data-transition="fade" CausesValidation="false"
                data-theme="b" data-icon="" Text="Back" onclick="btnBack_Click" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use ValidatorGroups to separate the validations.